# Multiple load functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm curious if there is a better way to handle multiple `load()` functions on one page? I've got this code right here:

```
setInterval(function update() {
    if (denial) return;
    denial = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        error: function () {
            denial = false;
        },
        complete: function () {
            denial = false;
            $('#loader').hide("slow");
            $('#credits').load('world1.php?mode=money');
            $('#fuelleft').load('world1.php?mode=fuel');
            $('#energyleft').load('world1.php?mode=energy');
            $('#starmap').show("slow");
            $('#upgrade-holder').load('world1.php?mode=up');
        },
    });
}, 1000);
```

It works perfectly fine, but is there any way I could improve this code?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! If the code works perfectly fine and you're just looking for someone to look over your code and see if you could improve them, you might like to take a look at [codereview.se]. If there is an issue with your code that you know about though, [so] is suitable for those types of questions.

Answer (score 3):

`update.php` could include all the content that needed to be updated. You could then update that with `html`, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#credits').html(data.money);
        $('#fuelleft').html(data.fuel);
        $('#energyleft').html(data.energy);
        // ...
    }
});
```

This code here assumes that `update.php` returns JSON that looks like this:

```
{"money":"<p>some HTML to go into #credits</p>","fuelleft":"<p>more HTML</p>",…}
```

…but you could easily modify it for other output formats.